# Discrete Convolution, Mathematica

Tags: convolution, discrete

I can't find the discrete Convolution [1] in mathematica,
neither DiscreteConvolve nor ListConvolve do "what I want",

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4}
b = {1, 1, 1, 1}
c = {1, 0, 1, 0}
MagicConvolve[a,b]
Out:= {3, 6, 10, 9}
MagicConvolve[a,c]
Out:= {2, 4, 6, 3}
```

Thanks in advance!

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution

edit: I edited the Out:='s because I misscalculated them in my head yesterday, sorry and thanks for the help

edit2: In numpy it would be

```
np.convolve([1,2,3,4], [1,1,1,1],'same')
```

Comment: I don't think your calculations are aligned with the formula in Wikipedia article. ListConvolve has lots of options for how to handle end conditions.

Comment: In a convolution the products are summed up. But your examples looks more like: "pick elements of a if corresponding element of b are 1, otherwise set them to zero".

Comment: Here's a definition that accomplishes what you ask for: magicConvolve[x_, y_] := x y;
Then magicConvolve[a, b] and magicConvolve[a, c] are precisely as you request, though this is normally not called "convolution".

Comment: @bills small thing: I think you need `magicConvolve[x_, y_] := x Reverse[y]` to get `magicConvolve[a, c]` to come out the way the example does!

Comment: @thorimur -- good point. It does need to be reversed. I'm still not clear on how this should be generalized beyond the two examples though.

Comment: I am so sorry! I misscalculated the Outs
I edited them now, sorry and thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try  `ListConvolve[a, b, 2, 0]  (*  {3, 6, 10, 9}  *)`  and `ListConvolve[a, c, 2, 0]  (*  {2, 4, 6, 3}  *)` ?

Answer (score 4):

ListConvolve is exactly what you want. But since it is a fairly general function, you need to specify the options correctly to get the specific end conditions you desire. Here is your example:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4}
b = {1, 1, 1, 1}
c = {1, 0, 1, 0}

ListConvolve[a, b, 2, 0]
{3, 6, 10, 9}

ListConvolve[a, c, 2, 0]
{2, 4, 6, 3}
```

As it says in the help file, the third element gives the alignment of the two sequences (where to start) and the fourth specifies the padding. So "2" and "0" correspond to numpy's 'same' option. A good exercise would be to figure out what Mathematica options in ListConvolve correspond to the other two numpy options 'full' and 'valid'.

Comment: Thanks alot! I was playing around but seems to have missread the help-function!